# Bootstrap - Large logo beside NavBar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a navbar that is a fraction of the size of the logo, and allows for additional content to be place underneath it. Like this:

[image: Example]

The jsFiddle below shows what I have now. The black line shows the bottom of the nav bar, which has extended to be the same size as the image.

I have tried setting the height of the nav bar to 50px, but that causes all content underneath it to move up (which really throws the layout off). I have also tried surrounding everything with containers, but that also did not seem to work. I imagine any solution will involve one or both of those ideas, but I am not sure how to implement it.

[**Here's a Demo in jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/)

Here's my code:

```
<div class ="container-fluid">
<a href="#" class="pull-left"><img id="logo" class="img-responsive" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQevVAv_ZVUfI8i5cMpRZGbIu71MGjPUqR70qR7F877JKyWJWdEXw"></a>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo.jpg"></a> -->
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The fiddle you linked to is just generic boilerplate.  Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z0947k7p/) with your actual code.  I also converted the image to just use imgur so it won't move over time when you've moved on, but the question remains here.

Comment: Thank you for that, and the help formatting. The question looks much better now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you a good place to start when it comes to mixing columns and nav elements together while keeping everything orderly and responsive.

Make sure to include Bootstrap CSS, JS and jQuery or your mobile nav toggle won't open. Working example

```css
.navbar.navbar-default {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-left: transparent;
}
#navbar-collapse {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #266080;
}
.lower-nav {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 23px 20px;
  height: 78px;
  color: #266080;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #266080;
}
#brand-logo {
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}
#brand-logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  min-width: 150px;
}
div.nopadding {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav-buttons {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand {
  display: none;
}
.wrapper {
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.well {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #428bca;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .lower-nav {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 25px 20px;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .lower-nav {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 hidden-xs nopadding">
      <div id="brand-logo">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350/266080/fff?text=Home" alt="Home" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 nopadding">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Search</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Archives</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Education</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="lower-nav"><span class="title">Text here</span>

          <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <div class="btn btn-info nav-buttons">Hello</div>
            <div class="btn btn-warning nav-buttons">Hello</div>
            <div class="btn btn-danger nav-buttons">Hello</div>
            <div class="btn btn-default nav-buttons">Hello</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="well"> <a href="http://getbootstrap.com//">Bootstrap 3</a> 
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ultrices enim id tortor tincidunt, eget mollis mauris gravida. Mauris sem leo, feugiat ut felis blandit, imperdiet egestas orci. Proin lacinia at massa fermentum facilisis. Donec laoreet
    facilisis nunc, sed posuere magna rhoncus sed. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent augue ipsum, rhoncus vel tempus sed, vehicula non purus. Nunc sit amet consectetur risus. Integer eget justo ut sapien consectetur
    auctor id eu augue. Quisque ac elit congue, eleifend lectus a, tempor purus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus gravida massa arcu, sed sodales orci interdum vel. Curabitur ullamcorper leo mauris, ut interdum felis mollis id. Nunc porttitor
    egestas fringilla. Suspendisse volutpat sem quis sagittis fermentum. Fusce in laoreet elit. Etiam aliquam varius tincidunt.</p>
  <p>Nunc nisi justo, ultricies at lobortis et, fermentum at dolor. Nulla ultrices erat et erat egestas, in luctus justo pellentesque. In convallis purus ut pellentesque interdum. Curabitur in neque lectus. Nullam lobortis sodales elit, eu fringilla eros
    aliquet vel. Aliquam ac ipsum vel nunc vestibulum luctus nec sit amet mauris. Ut viverra ornare risus eu condimentum. Fusce sollicitudin volutpat nisl id dignissim. Sed malesuada dui at magna imperdiet, non accumsan odio imperdiet. Etiam tristique
    fermentum enim, vel dictum nulla fermentum ac. Etiam in bibendum nisi. Vestibulum neque lectus, vehicula eu sagittis ut, blandit sit amet mi.</p>
  <p>Maecenas lacinia vestibulum magna. Integer mollis varius ullamcorper. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam sit amet tortor turpis. Cras pharetra tellus elit, nec iaculis erat pellentesque
    sit amet. Nullam varius felis vel velit fermentum, nec facilisis erat accumsan. Nullam facilisis orci quam, eget semper turpis dictum id. Aenean magna ante, lobortis id sollicitudin quis, dapibus nec nisi. Maecenas aliquet posuere lectus, a ultricies
    arcu sodales sodales. Proin dignissim facilisis consectetur. Pellentesque suscipit quis dui eget malesuada. Quisque cursus neque a faucibus egestas. Phasellus sed nulla scelerisque diam adipiscing suscipit. Etiam sit amet enim ultricies risus consequat
    vestibulum eu sit amet urna.</p>
  <p>Vivamus hendrerit eget augue viverra auctor. Praesent mi leo, facilisis vel nisi vitae, sodales rhoncus augue. Maecenas purus nunc, commodo at massa eu, blandit aliquet enim. Proin sem neque, imperdiet non arcu eu, sagittis malesuada est. Fusce enim
    neque, facilisis et mattis ut, vulputate sed justo. Vivamus elementum elit nunc, eget tempor erat adipiscing nec. Praesent vestibulum dapibus vehicula. Pellentesque viverra faucibus leo in ornare. Sed sodales faucibus tincidunt. Vivamus dignissim
    tristique libero sit amet aliquet. Donec ut nunc dolor. Duis molestie tortor mi, id auctor nisi ullamcorper et. Proin eu ante cursus, varius felis id, porta orci.</p>
  <p>Aliquam imperdiet scelerisque purus, nec sagittis mi auctor vitae. Maecenas sodales scelerisque massa, vitae iaculis neque tincidunt sed. Vivamus id imperdiet lectus. Fusce id tellus ut tellus volutpat hendrerit in at justo. Duis eu tempus nibh. Nunc
    consectetur euismod sapien, eget placerat metus tempor sit amet. Maecenas at sem ac purus dictum viverra. Praesent eu neque in metus congue dictum eu in dolor. Mauris a elit sem. Quisque non velit malesuada ligula aliquet lacinia. Donec congue, leo
    lacinia vulputate pulvinar, est justo venenatis nisi, sit amet condimentum massa sem sed urna. Duis eget pretium eros. Sed et rutrum leo, sit amet sollicitudin urna. Nullam dui augue, malesuada sed lectus sed, malesuada fringilla massa.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have another question for you - hopefully you will see this. Here is an [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9871/) that is almost entirely your code. When the screen gets small enough, and the navbar is collapsed, the logo image goes away. I would really like to have collapsed navbar, with the buttosn underneath it and the image logo on the left hand side. Thank you so much again for your original answer, the code is gorgeous.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a row and some columns as I have done below. Placing your image in the first column to the left and then the nav bar in the second column.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a href="#" class="pull-left">
            <img id="logo" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/yhGyJ8P.png" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
                        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo.jpg">
        </a> -->
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: I really like this, it looks great and is exactly what I was asking for. One problem that I see with it though - when you resize the window, making it smaller, the menu collapses, but still opens under the logo. I would really like to have it expand from the button that is clicked. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: You can change the `class="col-md-xx"` that I added to `class="col-xs-xx"`. That will prevent the column from stacking at any screen width but your menu will still collapse leaving the image to the left. Although the image will be quite small at really small screen widths. You may want to consider adding a min-width to the image so it doesn't get too small.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jx6e857y/

Here is another example you could use with some bootstrap css overrides.

**HTML:**
    
        
            
             Toggle navigation

```
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Search</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Archives</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Education</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <br />
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <span class="additional-text">This is your additional text</span>
        </div>

    </nav>
```

**CSS overrides:** (Make sure this is after your bootstrap.css file)

```
/*md+ DESKTOP */
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .collapse.navbar-collapse .nav.navbar-nav:first-child {
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    }
    .collapse.navbar-collapse .container-fluid {
        float:right;
    }
    .additional-text {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        margin-bottom:8px;
        margin-left:8px;
        font-size:22px;
        color:grey;
        cursor:arrow;
    }
}
/* md- overrides MOBILE */
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .collapse.navbar-collapse .nav.navbar-nav:first-child {
        border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .collapse.navbar-collapse .nav.navbar-nav:first-child li:last-child {
        border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .collapse.navbar-collapse .nav.navbar-nav:last-child li:first-child a {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    .navbar-header img {
        max-height:80px;
    }
    .collapse.navbar-collapse.in .nav.navbar-nav {
        float:none !important;
        display:block;
    }
    .additional-text {
        position:relative;
        font-size:22px;
        display:none;
    }
}
```